# Protect rest ful web services

Tags: web-services, rest, backbone.js

I'm developing an application to search events. I'm using backbone.js to build this application. I have some web services to get the information about the events. For example, I have a web service to get all the events in database, another web service to get information about an event given an id, etc... I would to know if it is possible protect my web services, for that people can not access.

In my code I have a collection that have a url that corresponds a web service:

```
ev.models.ImagemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: 'http:/.../.../webservices/services/events/',

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Collection Home Inicializado");
    }

});
```

If I access the DevTools in web browser, with some search I can find url with web service, but I would like hide this information somehow.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The RESTful routes are configured in your backend, and if you want to disallow users to access them, you need to create a filter on your backend route that is executed before the route is hit.

This is the case when you (for example) want to only give access when the user authenticates. The filter you apply on the route is custom, you can define it whichever way you want; in this case the filter checks the "authenticated" status.
Whenever the user did not authenticate, your filter can then return a message from the backend, saying something like eg. "You need to authenticate first."

Comment: OK, but my inicial page get the events from database, and the user should see the events. If only give access when the user authenticates, then the user can not see the events in inicial page. :/

Comment: Ok I see. You don't really want to protect the web service, you just want to hide the url? You cannot really "protect" it as such, because you indicate that you actually want to load the events on the frontpage, which makes that it is accessible to everyone... When you make a RESTful request, the navigation tab of your browser shows the URL to which the request is made, so it is never private. The only thing you can do is monitor the traffic.

Comment: Yes, basically I want that url not want it to be visible to other users. If I create a middleware in php, when sending a request to the php file and then receive response from it. This could help?

Comment: You could try to do that. Most REST api's are public though, and monitored through the use of an API key to control the bandwidth usage. We're also developing an application that works with events (activities), but decided to make the API public in order to generate more exposure and ultimately a larger community over time, which is important from a business point of view.